# SimpleDateFormat ThreadSafe Suggestion-> creating new object is better or ThreadLocal is?

Tags: java, multithreading, simpledateformat, thread-local

I am building an application in which there i have to format date. For formatting i am using

```
SimpleDateFormatter class.
```

As per my knowledge there are three ways to use this class with synchronization

1) create local variable with

```
 new SimpleDateFormatter("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

2) use synchronized keyword

```
synchronized(this) {
      simpleDateFormatter.format(date); //use static object and then format with synchronization
}
```

3) use thread local variable with Simple Date Formatter like this

```
private static ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> outDateFormatHolder = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {
@Override
protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

I am building web application, where i can receive multiple request and at some point i will be formatting the date.

Now i know that if i have to format more than once in the same thread then ThreadLocal would have been better option.

But according to current scenario every thread will format the date once.

Question-> the whole question boils to the situation. What will be a better option 1 or 3, since option 2 will have performance issue.

As i have to format only once,

---------> are option 1 and option 3 same ?, if they are not, which one is better in my case?

------> is there any other way to make it threadsafe which will not have performance or memory issue(as read in case of ThreadLocal).

I am open to suggestion. Please share your opinions.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: An alternative is to use Apache Commons Lang's [`FastDateFormat`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html) class, which is a thread-safe version of `SimpleDateFormatter`.

Comment: Thanks i guess this is a better option.

Comment: Keep it simple and just create a new instance when you need it. I doubt that this will cause any performance problems.

Comment: I have to process a large volume of request around 10,000 per second. Since Object creation of SimpleDateFormatter is not that light, it will definately have impact on performance

Comment: @ParasMittal It might have an impact on performance, but it's debatable. Do remember the [Rules of Optimisation](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization).

Comment: 10,000 objects of SimpleDateFormatter is nothing. Its a few KBs worth of object. Don't jump on conclusions without factual data.

Comment: As far as i can conclude,There are only two options now-> go for object creation or use FastDateFormat.           I think  I should go for new object creation, measure performance with Jmeter and then use FastDateFormat as suggested by @Duncan and measure performance. After the results i will decide. Thanks guys for all your valuble suggestion. I appreciate that.

Comment: @ParasMittal I would encourage an even more relaxed approach than that. Bear in mind the first two rules of optimization. Just write the rest of your program and only if the resulting application is too slow *and* you can later identify this part of the code is the slowest, then think about this again.

Comment: @Duncan I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your situation is that single thread will have to format the date only once, then there's no point going with ThreadLocal, you can simple create new object every time.

Since the object is creating nevertheless of the situation, in this case using ThreadLocal will be costly and might have memory issue. My suggestion -> go for new Object creation.

I think you are right about synchronization because it will block the threads and since you have to process such a large request of around 10,000 per second.

Another option would be to use Apache Commons Lang's FastDateFormat class as suggested by @Duncan.

Hope this is the answer you are looking for...

Comment: Thanks @Atul Sharma, This is what i have been looking for.

Comment: +1 Or you can use the JSR-310 back port as JSR-310, based on Joda Time, is the preferred option in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateFormatter` is a fairly light weight construct. Depending on the volume of call on the `SimpleDateFormatter` for parsing and formatting, if you use use synchronized and share a single instance you would end up having loads of blocked threads there.

Its far better and easier to create a new instance and use it when you need.

Comment: I am actually confused between ThreadLocal and making new instance everytime. I know for sure using synchronized keyword will have performance issue.

Comment: ThreadLocal would keep a copy of the SimpleDateFormatter for each thread that comes in. But ThreadLocal is very dangerous as it can cause memory leaks. Read the section "Thread Confinement – Thread Local copies" at http://walivi.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/concurrency-in-java-a-beginners-introduction/ It explains the potential problems and scenario when you should use it.